# Parsing XML documents with LXML

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xml, lxml

I'm new to LXML, and parsing XML documents in general. I have written a small section of code that appears to do what I need it too do, but it feels like I have overly complicated it. Is there any way I can simplify this?

Method:

```
def importFromXML(self, filename):
    tree = etree.parse(filename)
    for child in tree.getroot():
        if child.tag != 'SLOT':
            print('Tag:', child.tag, ', Text', child.text)
        elif child.tag == 'SLOT':
            for slot, index in child.items():
                for attribute in child:
                    print('Slot Number =', index, ', Tag:', attribute.tag, ', Value:', attribute.text)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
<ActiveState>drop</ActiveState>
<Location>Left Wrist</Location>
<Realm>All</Realm>
<ItemName>Band of the Dream Conqueror</ItemName>
<ItemQuality>100</ItemQuality>
<Equipped>1</Equipped>
<Level>50</Level>
<TYPE>Wrist</TYPE>
<SOURCE>Drop</SOURCE>
<DBSOURCE>kscraft</DBSOURCE>
<SLOT Number="0">
    <Type>Resist</Type>
    <Effect>Crush</Effect>
    <Amount>6</Amount>
</SLOT>
<SLOT Number="1">
    <Type>Resist</Type>
    <Effect>Thrust</Effect>
    <Amount>6</Amount>
</SLOT>
<SLOT Number="2">
    <Type>Resist</Type>
    <Effect>Slash</Effect>
    <Amount>6</Amount>
</SLOT>
</Item>
```

I just want to make sure I'm doing this right. I'm using Python 3.x. Eventually I will be doing more with the data I pull, but for right now I'm just trying to pull the information, and figure out the most optimized way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't actually *doing* much, there's little to review to be honest, it's not looking complicated for what it is.  Of course don't just have everything in a couple of loops, perhaps have some handlers to dispatch on the tags or so (`handlers[child.tag](child)` ...).

I suppose if you wanted a relatively quick way to *write* the importer code, [consider XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python).  If you wanted quick processing (by not building up the full DOM in memory), [consider using a SAX handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263029/how-to-get-results-from-xml-sax-parser-in-python).

Finally, there might be a library to automatically map the XML to a class structure, or even parse it directly into `dict` instances or something, if you prefer that, but I don't any off the top of my hat.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just trying to find the most optimized way to pull the information, then I will do something with it later. There is a lot of terminology that I will need to look up (new to both Python and XML parsing) and see how I can apply it. The XML files are at most 25 lines, and it would be ideal if I could load the `<SLOT>` elements in a dict that gives me `{ SLOT: {'Index': value, 'Type': value, 'Effect': value, 'Amount': value}}` perhaps that will be my next step.